# Hyper-Kaehler Strucutre for Compact Lie Groups?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, quaternionic-geometry

We know from the classy work of Joyce that "any compact Lie group becomes hypercomplex after it is multiplied by a sufficiently big torus". The quote comes from the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_manifold).

I am asking if it is known that these hypercomplex manifolds are hyper-Kaehler (or hyper-Hermitian) or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is already 'no' for the simplest case:
$$
S^1\times \mathrm{SU}(2) = (\mathbb{H}{\setminus}\{0\})/\mathbb{Z},
$$
which is clearly hypercomplex, but cannot even be Kähler, much less hyperKähler.

Comment: Can we put on it something weaker, like an Hermitian structure, or an almost-symplectic?

Comment: @TomaszKöner:  Yes, since these are only topological questions.  In fact, any complex manifolds supports almost-symplectic structures and Hermitian structures.  This is essentially because $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathrm{Sp}(n,\mathbb{R})\subset \mathrm{SL}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ each contain $\mathrm{U}(n)$ as a maximal compact subgroup. (Hence, the latter is a deformation retract of each of the two former (non-compact) groups.)